# No module named buildout.buildout

Tags: zope, buildout

I'm trying to setup a Zope app following the steps in the [official tutorial](https://zope.readthedocs.io/en/latest/INSTALL-buildout.html).
After downloading the Zope distribution and bootstrapping the buildout, I get to the last step, `bin/buildout`, and this error follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/buildout", line 9, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.buildout
ImportError: No module named buildout.buildout
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Try instead the instructions in

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bobtemplates.plone (call it from the src-directory)
and
https://github.com/plone/bobtemplates.plone

and use a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv mrbobvenv
source mrbobvenv/bin/activate
```